# Why my activity can't enter onStop after go to another activity from StatusBar sometimes?

Tags: android

Why my activity can't  enter onStop after go to another activity from StatusBar sometimes?
Description:
1,Start Activity A
2,pull down the statusbar, and then choose another activity B to start

result:
sometimes, Activity A enter onStop, sometimes, it's not. Why?

Test device: HTC HD android phone

Comment: Does it enter onPause() ?  Technically, after it does, it can be killed with no further notification methods called, though that would probably happen only if the system runs low on resources.

Comment: Yes, it always can enter onPause. If the system runs low on resources, it can enter onStop. So this case is normal, is it right?

Comment: No, onStop() occurs after onPause() when your activity ceases to be displayed, typically because something else is displayed.  But in a low resources case, onPause() may be the only thing that happens, your app's process may simply be killed after that with none of onPause(), onDestroy() etc called.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is onPause that is called. see doc activity lifecycle here  developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html